# nr edges in hamitonian graph, proof correct?

Tags: graph-theory

I tried to proof te following:

Every undirected graph $(V,E)$ with n nodes and at least $\frac{n^2-3n+6}{2}$ edges contains a Hamiltonian cycle.

I did this as follows:

($\forall u,v:u\neq v: \{u,v\}\notin E \implies deg(u)+deg(v)\geq n$)$\implies (V,E) \, contains\,Hamiltonian\,cycle$

Now to do a proof by contradiction assume $(V,E)$ does not contain Hamiltonian cycle.
This means $\lnot \forall u,v:u\neq v: \{u,v\}\notin E \implies deg(u)+deg(v)\geq n$

$Take \{u,v\}\notin E \land deg(u)+deg(v)\lt n$

$now\, remove\, u\, and\, v\, from\, the\, graph$

$deg(u)+deg(v)\lt n ,\, \#E\geq \frac{n^2-3n+6}{2}$

$after\, removing\, u\, and\, v\, from\, the\, graph,\, at\, least$

$\frac{n^2-3n+6}{2} -\frac{2n-2}{2}=\frac{n^2-5n+8}{2} edges\, have\, to\, be\, left$

$but\, after\, removing\, u\, and\, v,\, only\, n-2\, vertices\, are\, left,\, so\, at\, most$

$\frac{(n-2)(n-3)}{2}=\frac{n^2-5n+6}{2} edges\,can\, still\,be\,in\,the\,graph$

$which\, means\, we\, have\, a\, contradiction$

Answer (score 1):

This is a valid proof. Someone grading it may decide that you are not allowed to use Ore's theorem, but that does not affect the validity.